# How to retrieve the actual value of the "link with editor" button in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a eclipse plugin and i'm implementing the link with editor functionality.

My question is:

How do we know (on the EditorPart when this is activated) the actual value of the state of the link with editor command button (IWorkbenchCommandConstants.NAVIGATE_TOGGLE_LINK_WITH_EDITOR) if is active or not? in order to do something or not.

By the way is there any example source of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one setting for this, rather it is specific to individual views. You can have Package Explorer with linking set and Project Explorer with linking off at the same time.

The views with linking set just use `IPartListener2` to listen to part changes. So there is no easy way to determine if this is set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a [link helper extension](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_navigator_linkHelper.html), which in turn uses an implementation of [ILinkHelper](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api32/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/ILinkHelper.html) to map forth and back between navigator selection and editor.

However, as long as IFiles are shown in the navigator and as long as your custom editor uses a IFileEditorInput, you don't need to do anything, as this is covered by the standard [ResourceLinkHelper](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api32/org/eclipse/ui/internal/navigator/resources/workbench/ResourceLinkHelper.html). Setting a breakpoint into that class is the best way to debug the flow in a standard Eclipse application.

That said, you should not watch the toggle button state as such at all.